# Form template for generating pdf file with list item

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I have a task that requires generating a pdf that has the salary details of an employee. The data is stored in a custom list. I need to use some kind of template for the pdf to show the data in an organized manner. How do I get on with it?

I have to do it in an autohosted app that goes to a office 365 site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first added a template to a doc library that was of the excel type. Then I used microsoft.office.interop.excel to edit an instance of the template in a workbook and then convert it into pdf.

```
//For workbook:

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = app.Workbook.Open("templateurl", ...parameters...);
Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets;
Worksheet sh =(Worksheet) sheets.get_Item(1);

//then populate it
sh.Cells[row, column] = value
.
.
.
.

// save it locally

sh.SaveAs("d:\temp\demo.xslx");
```

Then I uploaded it to another document library then used

```
workBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(targetType, targetPath, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

That gave me the pdf :)